# Error Permission Denied When Saving a File in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, octave

I am using MATLAB 2012 on Windows 7. Reading an xlsx file, which contains one column numeric and other text as follows

```
[a1,a2]=xlsread('test.xlsx');
id=a1(:,1); %// numeric
Type=a2(:,2); %// Text
unique_type=unique(Type);
unique_id=unique(id);
ug=unique_type;
```

Up to now it works fine, but when I type

```
save Unique_Type.mat ug;
```

It shows an error

```
Error using save    
Unable to write file unique_type.mat: permission denied.
```

Comment: Did you check permissions? Is writing in the directory possible?

Comment: Yes, by using `[success, message] = fileattrib`. I got 1 for UserRead and UserWrite.

Comment: Is there enough space on your hard drive to write to file? A long shot, but I might as well ask.

Comment: Yes, I have. Moreover it is a very small file.

Comment: Did you try writing to another directory? Is it just that particular one that is causing the problem?

Comment: Could it be the file exists and is locked by another program? Virus scanners just love to do that.

Comment: Dear rayryeng, thanks, worked for the time being. But I guess there must be some permanent solution to this which I could not figure out. Dear  bdecaf, it is not so. There does not exist such file already.

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab write command PWD 
it will give you directory or folder in which matlab is trying to save file 
So problem is with the permission of that folder your OS is not giving permission to Matlab to write files So Solve this issue Copy 
the path that PWD command has given you
Paste that in Windows Explorer 
Go to that folder's Properties than go to security 
and change the permission of as per your requirements that worked for me